# Java - Using List to specify Client

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

Here is the code for my messaging program. It is comprised of three jframe files, a server file and two client files. So far, the code achieves half of the requirements, with both clients being able to send a message and the server receieving and displaying it. However I am confused as to how to extend the code so that client A will recieve the message sent by client B and vice versa.

The server code is:

```
package Chats;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Chat_Server extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{

    static ServerSocket ss;

    public Chat_Server() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Msg_Area = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Msg_Area.setColumns(20);
        Msg_Area.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Msg_Area);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 332, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new Chat_Server().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        //String msgin = "";
        try
        {            
            ss = new ServerSocket(1201); // Server starts at 1201 port number
            ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<Socket>();

            while(true)
            { 
                Socket s = ss.accept(); // Now server will accept the connections.
                clients.add(s);

                new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    //@Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try                          
                        {         
                            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                            String msgin = "";

                            while (!msgin.equals("exit")) 
                            {           
                                msgin = din.readUTF();
                                Msg_Area.setText(Msg_Area.getText().trim() + "\n Client 1: \t" + msgin); // Displaying the message from client      
                            }

                            din.close();
                            dout.close();
                            s.close();
                            clients.remove(s);
                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                           //Exception Code Here 
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea Msg_Area;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Both of the clients have the code:

```
package Chats;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Chat_Client extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream dout;

    public Chat_Client() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Msg_Text = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        Msg_Area = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        Msg_Send = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Msg_Text.setText("jTextField1");

        Msg_Area.setColumns(20);
        Msg_Area.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(Msg_Area);

        Msg_Send.setText("jButton1");
        Msg_Send.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                Msg_SendActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 332, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(Msg_Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 257, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(Msg_Send)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 196, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Msg_Text, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(Msg_Send))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void Msg_SendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try
        {
            String msgout = "";
            msgout = Msg_Text.getText().trim();
            dout.writeUTF(msgout);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle exceptions here.
        }
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Chat_Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new Chat_Client().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        try
        {
            s = new Socket ("127.0.0.1", 1201); // Here the ip ddress is local address.
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            String msgin = "";

            while (!msgin.equals("exit"))
            {
                msgin = din.readUTF();
                Msg_Area.setText(Msg_Area.getText().trim() + "\n Client 2: \t" + msgin);
            }      
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Exception Code
        }    
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea Msg_Area;
    private javax.swing.JButton Msg_Send;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Msg_Text;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

All of the code uses the same "1201" port and both clients are connected using the localhost IP address. I want it to work so that I can run the server and then both clients and be able to send messages between them.